# How to debug a .net 4.0 program on Windows XP?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-xp

I have Windows 8 + Visual Studio 2013 and made a program that runs with .net 4.0 on Windows XP. I'd really like to debug it on Windows XP, but I have no idea how.
I guess I'd need Visual Studio 2010, but I can't find a legal download link for it.
Any other ideas what I could do?

Comment: MDbg is a very basic debugger that's easy to copy.  Nothing "visual" about it so do count on spending time on this.  If you want to support ancient operating systems then getting an MSDN subscription is pretty important btw.

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved my problem with Visual Express 2010. Under certain circumstances creating NamedPipeServerStream object behaves differently in Windows XP compared to 8 and throws "IOException: all pipe instances are busy". This NEVER happened in Windows 8. I couldn't find it because it happened in a task and I got a cryptic System.AggregateException because I didn't use try/catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download an .iso for Microsoft Visual Express 2010 for Windows XP and install it (for example) with virtual clone drive.
It works flawlessly, if you adapt your .sln file as explained here:
[open visual studio 2012 projects in visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895479/open-visual-studio-2012-projects-in-visual-studio-2008?answertab=votes#tab-top)